# How to automate torch option in iOS using appium?

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, appium-ios

I am automating an iOS Application, where i need to check if the user clicks on torch option, the device torch starts. And if the user again clicks on the torch icon the device torch gets turn off. can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code on Torch button.

```
@IBAction func btnFlashAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let avDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
    if (avDevice?.hasTorch)! {
        do {
            _ = try avDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
        }
        if on == true {
            avDevice?.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
            on = false
        } else {
            do {
                _ = try avDevice?.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
                on = true
            } catch {
            }
        }
        avDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, i am using core java to automate the iOS application, i did not get the code, could you please explain the above code in java?